# Limit filetype and wp media

Tags: jquery, javascript, media

**This is my input markup:**

```
<div class="button-primary" id="fileToUpload">Upload</div>
```

**This is js:**

```
jQuery( '#fileToUpload' ).click( function()
{
    var custom_uploader = wp.media
    ({
        title: 'Select',
        button: {
            text: 'Select'
        },
        multiple: false  // Set this to true to allow multiple files to be selected.
    })
    .on( 'select', function()
    {
        var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON();
        jQuery( '#previewImage' ).attr( 'src', attachment.url );
        jQuery( '.custom_media_url' ).val( attachment.url );
        jQuery( '.custom_media_id' ).val( attachment.id );
    })
    .open();
});
```

I want to limit the the file type to `jpg,jpeg and png`. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have shown your questions and i have found correction in it.

You need to update your code as below.

```
.on( 'select', function()
{
    var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON();
    if(attachment.mime == "image/jpg" || attachment.mime == "image/jpge" || attachment.mime == "image/png")
    {

       jQuery( '#previewImage' ).attr( 'src', attachment.url );
       jQuery( '.custom_media_url' ).val( attachment.url );
       jQuery( '.custom_media_id' ).val( attachment.id );
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please select jpg,jpeg and png type images only");
        custom_uploader.open();
        return;
    }
})
```

Thanks you!